# declaring function inside a function in C

Tags: c

I am reading KR C book and I face a function definition I don't understand. It's page 87 the `qsort()` function. It declares the `swap()` function inside `qsort()` function:

```
void qsort(args)
{
 ...
 void swap(arguments);
 ...
 swap(a,b);
}

void swap(arguments){
...
}
```

SHouldn't `swap()` function be declared outside of function? Why declare it inside `qsort()` function?

Comment: You can't use a function that isn't declared.  It doesn't particularly matter where you declare it, as long as you declare it before you use it and the declaration is in scope.

Comment: Isn't it's scope limited to inside the block where is defined? In this case `swap()` is only valid inside `qsort()` function

Comment: @Arash Yes. And in the part of the file after it's been defined, too, of course. Because deinition is declaration.

Comment: Correct.  This is kind of wierd, but it's valid.

Comment: I'd write an answer, but answer without relevant standards quote wouldn't be too useful I think... Yes, you can do it. It is done rarely, with questionable usefulness. I guess it expresses programmer's intent: this function should not be called from all over the place.

Comment: It's a bad idea because no warning will be given if you get the arguments wrong in the function declaration, just silent undefined behaviour

Comment: It's really just a simple forward reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you are reading the K&R C Programming Language and perhaps the Second Edition with ANSI C? There is a PDF at https://hassanolity.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf and on page 87 is a discussion of recursion using the quick sort algorithm.

See this Wikipedia topic comparing and contrasting various C standards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C

The K&R C books are old style C as the Second Edition copyright is 1988. Lots of good material there but it needs to be read from the perspective of being older style and the C standards have changed since ANSI C. The main thing has been better specifications about what compilers are supposed to declare as errors and warnings. There were things perfectly acceptable in ANSI C that are no longer acceptable with the modern C standards. A lot of work has gone into attempting to provide better static checking by compilers by tightening up the C programming language specifications and providing a few extra keywords and syntax.

There either should be a forward declaration for `swap()` or the definition of the function with its source code should appear before the function is actually used. This allows the C compiler to check the usage of a function against its declaration or definition in order to check for possible usage errors.

However with the C programming language if you use a function before it is either defined or declared you will typically get a warning such as this warning from Visual Studio 2013 `warning C4013: 'swap' undefined; assuming extern returning int`.

Some compilers, recent versions of `clang` and `gcc` come to mind as well as Visual Studio 2015, have begun implementing C11. Some compilers provide additional options to improve warnings and/or to turn some kinds of warnings into errors.

For example if I have the following source code in a file testit.c (notice the .c file extension for C source code) and compile with Visual Studio 2013 using a warning level of 4, I will get a set of warnings but no errors. Visual Studio compiles this as C source using the standards and rules for C which are looser than those for C++ even for the same syntax.

I compiled two different versions of this source, one with the forward declaration on line 2 commented out and one with it uncommented. Notice from the warnings that the C compiler of Visual Studio allows a function to be used without a forward declaration.

Notice when the forward declaration on line 2 is uncommented in the second run there is a warning about putting a forward declaration for a function within a function scope: `warning C4210: nonstandard extension used : function given file scope`.

Also notice that with the forward declaration available in the second run, the compiler is able to identify possible usage errors and issue warnings and in one case issue an actual error.

Notice that the number of arguments varies in both the first and second compile but only in the second compile with the forward declaration uncommented and available for the compiler do we see warnings about extra arguments.

```
int func1() {                        // line 1
//  int swap(int a, int b);          // line 2, forward declaration for function swap

    int j = swap(1, 2);

    return 0;
}

int func2() {                         // line 9
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    } mm = { 0 };

    int k = swap(4, 5, 8);             // line 16

    float ff = swap(4.0, 5.0, 8.0);    // line 18

    int k2 = swap(mm, 2, 3);           // line 20

    return 1;
}

int swap(int a, int b) {               // line 25
    return a + b;
}
```

The warnings are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  testit.c
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(4): warning C4013: 'swap' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(4): warning C4189: 'j' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(18): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(16): warning C4189: 'k' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(20): warning C4189: 'k2' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(18): warning C4189: 'ff' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>  ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Projects\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe
```

If I then uncomment the forward declaration for the function `swap()` I see the following compiler output of warnings along with errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  testit.c
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(2): warning C4210: nonstandard extension used : function given file scope
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(4): warning C4189: 'j' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(16): warning C4020: 'swap' : too many actual parameters
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(18): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(18): warning C4020: 'swap' : too many actual parameters
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(18): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(20): error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from '' to 'int'
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(20): warning C4024: 'swap' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit.c(20): warning C4020: 'swap' : too many actual parameters
```

Now the C++ programming language is different and does not allow this kind of looseness. Which is why though C++ shares a history with C, C++ is a different though related language.

If I copy the same source into a file testit2.cpp then compile I will see different errors.

First with the forward declaration of `swap()` commented out.

```
1>  testit2.cpp
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(4): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(16): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(18): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(20): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
```

And again with the forward declaration uncommented.

```
1>  testit2.cpp
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(4): warning C4189: 'j' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(16): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(18): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(20): error C3861: 'swap': identifier not found
```

And finally if I move the forward declaration of `swap()` out of the scope of function `func1()` into file scope so that it is now line 1 then I will see the following, different errors:

```
1>  testit2.cpp
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(4): warning C4189: 'j' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(16): error C2660: 'swap' : function does not take 3 arguments
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(18): error C2660: 'swap' : function does not take 3 arguments
1>c:\users\projects\consoleapplication3\testit2.cpp(20): error C2660: 'swap' : function does not take 3 arguments
```

Comment: K&R 2nd edition barely even follows "ANSI C", meaning C90. That being said, using Visual Studio to demonstrate modern C standard compliance isn't the best idea. The reason you can use functions in VS without a prototype, is because the VS C compiler is outdated, non-compliant crap. If you want to do modern C programming, stay clear of the K&R book and Visual Studio both.